# Is there any simple way of finding a matrix which commutes with a given (say, more complicated) matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose I want to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a hermitian matrix $A$, but $A$ is big and ugly. Is there an easy way to find another, nicer, hermitian matrix $B$, such that $AB=BA$ and so $A$ and $B$ share the same eigenvectors?

If the answer is no, what about this: if I could find a hermitian $C$, such that $AC-CA \neq 0$, but it's "close" to $0$, in the sense that all but a few entries are nonzero - could I then attempt to modify $C$ a little and get some $C'$ that commutes with $A$?

Comment: The identity matrix is hermitian ...

Comment: To Mark's point, $AB=BA$ isn't what you want, rather $AK=KB$ for some simple $B$ and invertible $K$.

Comment: Wait...how come then in quantum mechanics commuting operators have the same eigenbasis. But if the space is finite dimensional, they can just as well be represented as hermitian matrices? So why doesn't every operator have the same eigenbasis as the identity then? I'm confused...